# libstartup-notification0-dev Package missing in Void Linux to Compile i3 WM

Tags: i3, void-linux

I have been using Void Linux for more than a year now and very satisfied with the user experience. Till now I have not fell short of any utility, library or program that was not found the repo. However, today while compiling i3WM, I figured Void Linux did not have the libstartup-notification0-dev package which is a dependency for compiling i3WM. I have been an end-user of i3WM for more than 2 years, but thought of getting to the Dev side of it.

Below is the error for reference.

```
[prashant@void i3]$ meson ./build/ && cd ./build/
The Meson build system
Version: 0.60.3
Source dir: /home/prashant/i3
Build dir: /home/prashant/i3/build
Build type: native build
Project name: i3
Project version: 4.20.1
C compiler for the host machine: cc (gcc 10.2.1 "cc (GCC) 10.2.1 20201203")
C linker for the host machine: cc ld.bfd 2.35.1
Host machine cpu family: x86_64
Host machine cpu: x86_64
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wunused-value: YES
Program meson/meson-dist-script found: YES (/home/prashant/i3/meson/meson-dist-script)
Checking for function "strndup" : YES
Checking for function "mkdirp" : NO
Configuring config.h.in using configuration
Found git repository at /home/prashant/i3
Program /usr/bin/meson found: YES (/usr/bin/meson)
Library m found: YES
Library rt found: YES
Library iconv found: NO
Found pkg-config: /usr/bin/pkg-config (1.8.0)
Run-time dependency libstartup-notification-1.0 found: NO (tried pkgconfig)

meson.build:305:0: ERROR: Dependency "libstartup-notification-1.0" not found, tried pkgconfig
```

Here is the search result on the Void repo:

```
[prashant@void i3]$ sudo xbps-query -Rs libstartup-notification0-dev
```

Anyone has a workaround for this?
Requesting Void Linux maintainers to kindly get this package/library in the repository.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In Void it is named `startup-notification-devel`, as you can find looking at [build template](https://github.com/void-linux/void-packages/blob/master/srcpkgs/i3/template) or using less strict search term in xbps-query.

Comment: A little late :)...but thanks @Chocimier

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the [`Extra`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/official_repositories#extra) repository, then install the [`startup-notification`](https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/startup-notification/).

Comment: As I am using Void Linux, this "Extra" repository is not needed. Thanks, anyways! Peace.